# How to call / Generate exceptions from the Mockito class for the Save method which does not return value?

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito, powermockito

I am using **Spring Data JPA + Mockito** example for writing service code. While writing a test case, I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException>
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:380)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:126)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:353)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:331)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.mastercard.customer.data.management.service.StudentServiceTest.test_Exception(StudentServiceTest.java:110)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

    at com.yyyy.StudentServiceImpl.convertToEntity(StudentServiceImpl.java:72)
    at com.yyyy.StudentServiceImpl.saveStudent(StudentServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.zzzzz.service.StudentServiceTest.test_Exception(StudentServiceTest.java:110)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    ... 6 more
```

Service Code:

```
public Student saveStudent(StudentDto dto) {
    Student studentEntity = convertToEntity(dto);
    Student student = null;
    try {
        student = studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error", ex);
    }
    return student;
}
```

**Test case**

```
@Test(expected = ResponseStatusException.class)
public void test_Exception() {
    studentMock = null;
    when(studentRepositoryMock.save(studentMock)).thenReturn(studentMock);

    doThrow(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error", ex))
            .when(studentServiceImpl.saveStudent(studentDtoMock));
}
```

**Note**: I want to write test case for both the `DataIntegrityViolationException` and `Exception` scenarios.

Comment: Instead of `.thenReturn` you can use `thenThrow` or `thenAnswer` for more complex cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using below.

```
@Test(expected = ResponseStatusException.class)
public void test_Exception() {
    doThrow(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error", ex))
        .when(studentRepositoryMock).save(any());
    studentServiceImpl.saveStudent(studentDtoMock);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You just need to move the method invocation outside of `when()`:

```
doThrow(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error", ex))
            .when(studentServiceImpl)
            .saveStudent(studentDtoMock);
```

Comment: Now, its saying `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException`